# how I get values of length of JSON with Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I want to use JSON length to show data in table view but I don't know how to get length in json

```
let url = "url/json.php"
Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: ["id":ids])
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response) // URL response
            print(response.data)     // server data
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")
            }
    }
```

for examples

```
    {a=11,b=12},{a=21,b=22}
length = 2
```

Comment: Please be more specific about the length you're looking for. Possibilities include the length of the character datastream returned from the request, or the number of elements in the first level of the tree. There are probably others and it matters what it is precisely that you're looking for

Comment: I'll edited thanks

Comment: it looks like array of dictionary  , and both array and dictionary have count property

Comment: Mike is correct – you could print the count value for value. You could also look into a number of cocoapods that will parse Json for you Alamo fire to Jason is one of them and works well

Comment: I'll solved this problem now thanks

Comment: @YasuhiroKondo How did you solve it? Please post the solution as an answer. Or if it's not a reproducible issue, just delete the question. :)

Comment: use `JSON.count` to count length

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the JSON constant value to an array.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3:

```
{ response in 
    if let allObjects = response.result.value as? NSArray{ 
     print("Array length is \(allObjects.count)")
}
}
```